# Extract a regex capture group from a string in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

For example:

Regex: `District ([0-9]{1,2})([^0-9]|$)`

Input `District 12 2021` returns `12`

Input `Southern District 3` returns `3`

Input `FooBar` returns `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `REGEXP_SUBSTR` doesn't allow extracting a single capturing group.

You can use e.g. `REGEXP_REPLACE(input, regex, '\\1')` to replace occurrences of `regex` in `input` with the first capture group of `regex`.

The following stored function makes this easy to use:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION regexp_extract(inp TEXT, regex TEXT, capture INT) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE capstr VARCHAR(5);
    DECLARE mregex TEXT;
    IF inp IS NULL OR LENGTH(inp) = 0 OR inp NOT REGEXP regex THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    SET capstr = CONCAT('\\', capture);
    SET mregex = CONCAT('.*', regex, '.*'); -- Want to match the entire input string so it all gets replaced
    RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE(inp, mregex, capstr);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Used like so:

```sql
SELECT regexp_extract('District 12 2021', 'District ([0-9]{1,2})([^0-9]|$)', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those users who might be stuck with an earlier version of MySQL or MariaDB which does not have `REGEXP_REPLACE` available, we can also use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('Southern District 3', 'District ', -1), ' ', 1);  -- 3
```